# Add Facebook Check-Ins to website

Tags: facebook, checkin

I have a website with different venue profile pages for a local community and we want to publish their checkins they have received on facebook. How can I display their checkins and is there anyway possible to separate the checkins based on male or female?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with FQL:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/

A sample query would be:

`SELECT author_uid, tagged_uids, message, timestamp FROM checkin WHERE page_id = 166793820034304`

This will only return public checkins, swap out the page_id used there with the IDs of the Pages you have created and you'll see any for that location. You can then use the author_uid and tagged_uids to query against the Graph API (or again FQL) User objects:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

This object includes a `gender` field.

Comment: Hello Matthew, since FQL will not be available anymore, do you have a new way of displaying facebook check-ins on a website?